# Graphics header fails to compile?

Tags: c, bgi

I downloaded the graphics.h and libbgi.a files and did exactly as the instructions provided and still it doesn't work! I've set linker parameters as well and I must say that this works in C++  mode , but not in C mode. I'm using Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2 as well. Here is what i get :

[image: My problem's screenshot photo]

Can anyone illustrate the problem for me?

P.S : The header code is

```
// The winbgim library, Version 6.0, August 9, 2004
// Written by:
//      Grant Macklem (Grant.Macklem@colorado.edu)
//      Gregory Schmelter (Gregory.Schmelter@colorado.edu)
//      Alan Schmidt (Alan.Schmidt@colorado.edu)
//      Ivan Stashak (Ivan.Stashak@colorado.edu)
//      Michael Main (Michael.Main@colorado.edu)
// CSCI 4830/7818: API Programming
// University of Colorado at Boulder, Spring 2003


// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                          Notes
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// * This library is still under development.
// * Please see http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi for information on
// * using this library with the mingw32 g++ compiler.
// * This library only works with Windows API level 4.0 and higher (Windows 95, NT 4.0 and newer)
// * This library may not be compatible with 64-bit versions of Windows
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------


// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                          Macro Guard and Include Directives
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef WINBGI_H
#define WINBGI_H
#include <windows.h>        // Provides the mouse message types
#include <limits.h>         // Provides INT_MAX
#include <sstream>          // Provides std::ostringstream
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------



// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                          Definitions
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Definitions for the key pad extended keys are added here.  When one
// of these keys are pressed, getch will return a zero followed by one
// of these values. This is the same way that it works in conio for
// dos applications.
#define KEY_HOME        71
#define KEY_UP          72
#define KEY_PGUP        73
#define KEY_LEFT        75
#define KEY_CENTER      76
#define KEY_RIGHT       77
#define KEY_END         79
#define KEY_DOWN        80
#define KEY_PGDN        81
#define KEY_INSERT      82
#define KEY_DELETE      83
#define KEY_F1          59
#define KEY_F2          60
#define KEY_F3          61
#define KEY_F4          62
#define KEY_F5          63
#define KEY_F6          64
#define KEY_F7          65
#define KEY_F8          66
#define KEY_F9          67

// Line thickness settings
#define NORM_WIDTH      1
#define THICK_WIDTH     3

// Character Size and Direction
#define USER_CHAR_SIZE  0
#define HORIZ_DIR       0
#define VERT_DIR        1


// Constants for closegraph
#define CURRENT_WINDOW -1
#define ALL_WINDOWS -2
#define NO_CURRENT_WINDOW -3

// The standard Borland 16 colors
#define MAXCOLORS       15
enum colors { BLACK, BLUE, GREEN, CYAN, RED, MAGENTA, BROWN, LIGHTGRAY, DARKGRAY,
              LIGHTBLUE, LIGHTGREEN, LIGHTCYAN, LIGHTRED, LIGHTMAGENTA, YELLOW, WHITE };

// The standard line styles
enum line_styles { SOLID_LINE, DOTTED_LINE, CENTER_LINE, DASHED_LINE, USERBIT_LINE };

// The standard fill styles
enum fill_styles { EMPTY_FILL, SOLID_FILL, LINE_FILL, LTSLASH_FILL, SLASH_FILL,
                   BKSLASH_FILL, LTBKSLASH_FILL, HATCH_FILL, XHATCH_FILL, INTERLEAVE_FILL,
                   WIDE_DOT_FILL, CLOSE_DOT_FILL, USER_FILL };

// The various graphics drivers
enum graphics_drivers { DETECT, CGA, MCGA, EGA, EGA64, EGAMONO, IBM8514, HERCMONO,
                        ATT400, VGA, PC3270 };

// Various modes for each graphics driver
enum graphics_modes { CGAC0, CGAC1, CGAC2, CGAC3, CGAHI, 
                      MCGAC0 = 0, MCGAC1, MCGAC2, MCGAC3, MCGAMED, MCGAHI,
                      EGALO = 0, EGAHI,
                      EGA64LO = 0, EGA64HI,
                      EGAMONOHI = 3,
                      HERCMONOHI = 0,
                      ATT400C0 = 0, ATT400C1, ATT400C2, ATT400C3, ATT400MED, ATT400HI,
                      VGALO = 0, VGAMED, VGAHI,
                      PC3270HI = 0,
                      IBM8514LO = 0, IBM8514HI };

// Borland error messages for the graphics window.
#define NO_CLICK        -1      // No mouse event of the current type in getmouseclick
enum graph_errors { grInvalidVersion = -18, grInvalidDeviceNum = -15, grInvalidFontNum,
                    grInvalidFont, grIOerror, grError, grInvalidMode, grNoFontMem,
                    grFontNotFound, grNoFloodMem, grNoScanMem, grNoLoadMem,
                    grInvalidDriver, grFileNotFound, grNotDetected, grNoInitGraph,
                    grOk };

// Write modes
enum putimage_ops{ COPY_PUT, XOR_PUT, OR_PUT, AND_PUT, NOT_PUT };

// Text Modes
enum horiz { LEFT_TEXT, CENTER_TEXT, RIGHT_TEXT };
enum vertical { BOTTOM_TEXT, VCENTER_TEXT, TOP_TEXT }; // middle not needed other than as seperator
enum font_names { DEFAULT_FONT, TRIPLEX_FONT, SMALL_FONT, SANS_SERIF_FONT,
             GOTHIC_FONT, SCRIPT_FONT, SIMPLEX_FONT, TRIPLEX_SCR_FONT,
             COMPLEX_FONT, EUROPEAN_FONT, BOLD_FONT };
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------



// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                              Structures
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// This structure records information about the last call to arc.  It is used
// by getarccoords to get the location of the endpoints of the arc.
struct arccoordstype
{
    int x, y;                   // Center point of the arc
    int xstart, ystart;         // The starting position of the arc
    int xend, yend;             // The ending position of the arc.
};


// This structure defines the fill style for the current window.  Pattern is
// one of the system patterns such as SOLID_FILL.  Color is the color to
// fill with
struct fillsettingstype
{
    int pattern;                // Current fill pattern
    int color;                  // Current fill color
};


// This structure records information about the current line style.
// linestyle is one of the line styles such as SOLID_LINE, upattern is a
// 16-bit pattern for user defined lines, and thickness is the width of the
// line in pixels.
struct linesettingstype
{
    int linestyle;              // Current line style
    unsigned upattern;          // 16-bit user line pattern
    int thickness;              // Width of the line in pixels
};


// This structure records information about the text settings.
struct textsettingstype
{
    int font;                   // The font in use
    int direction;              // Text direction
    int charsize;               // Character size
    int horiz;                  // Horizontal text justification
    int vert;                   // Vertical text justification
};


// This structure records information about the viewport
struct viewporttype
{
    int left, top,              // Viewport bounding box
        right, bottom;
    int clip;                   // Whether to clip image to viewport
};


// This structure records information about the palette.
struct palettetype
{
    unsigned char size;
    signed char colors[MAXCOLORS + 1];
};
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------



// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                          API Entries
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// Drawing Functions
void arc( int x, int y, int stangle, int endangle, int radius );
void bar( int left, int top, int right, int bottom );
void bar3d( int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int depth, int topflag );
void circle( int x, int y, int radius );
void cleardevice( );
void clearviewport( );
void drawpoly(int n_points, int* points);
void ellipse( int x, int y, int stangle, int endangle, int xradius, int yradius );
void fillellipse( int x, int y, int xradius, int yradius );
void fillpoly(int n_points, int* points);
void floodfill( int x, int y, int border );
void line( int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2 );
void linerel( int dx, int dy );
void lineto( int x, int y );
void pieslice( int x, int y, int stangle, int endangle, int radius );
void putpixel( int x, int y, int color );
void rectangle( int left, int top, int right, int bottom );
void sector( int x, int y, int stangle, int endangle, int xradius, int yradius );

// Miscellaneous Functions
int getdisplaycolor( int color );
int converttorgb( int color );
void delay( int msec );
void getarccoords( arccoordstype *arccoords );
int getbkcolor( );
int getcolor( );
void getfillpattern( char *pattern );
void getfillsettings( fillsettingstype *fillinfo );
void getlinesettings( linesettingstype *lineinfo );
int getmaxcolor( );
int getmaxheight( );
int getmaxwidth( );
int getmaxx( );
int getmaxy( );
bool getrefreshingbgi( );
int getwindowheight( );
int getwindowwidth( );
int getpixel( int x, int y );
void getviewsettings( viewporttype *viewport );
int getx( );
int gety( );
void moverel( int dx, int dy );
void moveto( int x, int y );
void refreshbgi(int left, int top, int right, int bottom);
void refreshallbgi( );    
void setbkcolor( int color );
void setcolor( int color );
void setfillpattern( char *upattern, int color );
void setfillstyle( int pattern, int color );
void setlinestyle( int linestyle, unsigned upattern, int thickness );
void setrefreshingbgi(bool value);
void setviewport( int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int clip );
void setwritemode( int mode );

// Window Creation / Graphics Manipulation
void closegraph( int wid=ALL_WINDOWS );
void detectgraph( int *graphdriver, int *graphmode );
void getaspectratio( int *xasp, int *yasp );
char *getdrivername( );
int getgraphmode( );
int getmaxmode( );
char *getmodename( int mode_number );
void getmoderange( int graphdriver, int *lomode, int *himode );
void graphdefaults( );
char *grapherrormsg( int errorcode );
int graphresult( );
void initgraph( int *graphdriver, int *graphmode, char *pathtodriver );
int initwindow
    ( int width, int height, const char* title="Windows BGI", int left=0, int top=0, bool dbflag=false, bool closeflag=true );
int installuserdriver( char *name, int *fp );    // Not available in WinBGI
int installuserfont( char *name );               // Not available in WinBGI
int registerbgidriver( void *driver );           // Not available in WinBGI
int registerbgifont( void *font );               // Not available in WinBGI
void restorecrtmode( );
void setaspectratio( int xasp, int yasp );
unsigned setgraphbufsize( unsigned bufsize );    // Not available in WinBGI
void setgraphmode( int mode );
void showerrorbox( const char *msg = NULL );

// User Interaction
int getch( );
int kbhit( );

// User-Controlled Window Functions (winbgi.cpp)
int getcurrentwindow( );
void setcurrentwindow( int window );
    
// Double buffering support (winbgi.cpp)
int getactivepage( );
int getvisualpage( );
void setactivepage( int page );
void setvisualpage( int page );
void swapbuffers( );

// Image Functions (drawing.cpp)
unsigned imagesize( int left, int top, int right, int bottom );
void getimage( int left, int top, int right, int bottom, void *bitmap );
void putimage( int left, int top, void *bitmap, int op );
void printimage(
    const char* title=NULL, 
    double width_inches=7, double border_left_inches=0.75, double border_top_inches=0.75,
    int left=0, int right=0, int right=INT_MAX, int bottom=INT_MAX,
    bool active=true, HWND hwnd=NULL
    );
void readimagefile(
    const char* filename=NULL,
    int left=0, int top=0, int right=INT_MAX, int bottom=INT_MAX
    );
void writeimagefile(
    const char* filename=NULL,
    int left=0, int top=0, int right=INT_MAX, int bottom=INT_MAX,
    bool active=true, HWND hwnd=NULL
    );

// Text Functions (text.cpp)
void gettextsettings(struct textsettingstype *texttypeinfo);
void outtext(char *textstring);
void outtextxy(int x, int y, char *textstring);
void settextjustify(int horiz, int vert);
void settextstyle(int font, int direction, int charsize);
void setusercharsize(int multx, int divx, int multy, int divy);
int textheight(char *textstring);
int textwidth(char *textstring);
extern std::ostringstream bgiout;    
void outstream(std::ostringstream& out=bgiout);
void outstreamxy(int x, int y, std::ostringstream& out=bgiout);    
    
// Mouse Functions (mouse.cpp)
void clearmouseclick( int kind );
void clearresizeevent( );
void getmouseclick( int kind, int& x, int& y );
bool ismouseclick( int kind );
bool isresizeevent( );
int mousex( );
int mousey( );
void registermousehandler( int kind, void h( int, int ) );
void setmousequeuestatus( int kind, bool status=true );

// Palette Functions
palettetype *getdefaultpalette( );
void getpalette( palettetype *palette );
int getpalettesize( );
void setallpalette( palettetype *palette );
void setpalette( int colornum, int color );
void setrgbpalette( int colornum, int red, int green, int blue );

// Color Macros
#define IS_BGI_COLOR(v)     ( ((v) >= 0) && ((v) < 16) )
#define IS_RGB_COLOR(v)     ( (v) & 0x03000000 )
#define RED_VALUE(v)        int(GetRValue( converttorgb(v) ))
#define GREEN_VALUE(v)      int(GetGValue( converttorgb(v) ))
#define BLUE_VALUE(v)       int(GetBValue( converttorgb(v) ))
#undef COLOR
int COLOR(int r, int g, int b); // No longer a macro

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#endif // WINBGI_H
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text.

Answer (score 1):

If it works in C++ mode, but not in C mode, that tell me that it's probably a C++ library. The fact that you get syntax errors in C mode, but not in C++ mode, lends credence to this hypothesis.

Assuming [this](http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs106b/cs106b.1126/materials/cppdoc/graphics-h.html) is what you're using (you should have specified that in your question), that's clearly C++ only, so no wonder you can't compile it as C code. You're hosed if you need to be able to use that library for C code. Still, you can write C-like code and just compile as C++ if you need. I just don't understand why you need to use a C++ library, but also need to compile as C and not C++.

Still, I'm only assuming that's the header file you're trying to include. Without further information on what you're trying to do, and exactly which library you're trying to use, I can only assume what the problem is.

EDIT: Based on the header you posted, it appears at first glance to be C compatible, except for including `<sstream>`. I have no idea if that's necessary or not. Someone with more experience might be a better resource to determine if that specific library would work in C.

Comment: That's actually not what i've used. I just copied the header code and i'm sure ( at least the provider claims so) that it's a C header file @Random Davis

Comment: The code you posted has the line `#include <sstream> `, which is C++. Thus, my answer still stands. But perhaps taking that line out might not affect that header. Still, you're probably better off using a much newer, more well-supported graphics library.

Comment: Yes your right.Can you specifically name one? @Random Davis